# No ressources availbable when running unit test

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

There's a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64887) in Android Studio where the app's ressources aren't available from within test classes.

The solution according to aforementioned thread is to put the following lines into the build.gradle:

```
task copyTestResources(type: Copy) {
    from "${projectDir}/src/test/resources"
    into "${buildDir}/classes/test"
}
processTestResources.dependsOn copyTestResources
```

but gradle says:

```
Error:(132, 0) Could not find property 'processTestResources' on project ':app'.
```

Where exactly do I have to put the line

```
processTestResources.dependsOn copyTestResources
```

within my build.gradle?

**EDIT:**

I didn't have `apply plugin: 'java'` in my build files yet. The problem is that in my app module's build gradle, I already have `apply plugin: 'android'` and trying to add the java plugin leads to

```
Error:The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins.
```

I tried puttin `apply plugin: 'java'` in the top level build file and then

```
task copyTestResources(type: Copy) {
    from "${projectDir}/app/src/test/resources"
    into "${buildDir}/classes/test"
}
```

Note that I added the modules directory to the from-line. This builds fine, but unit tests that need to access ressources still don't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was unaware that you were using the `android` plugin, sorry. You're getting the error because the Android plugin [defines a different set of build tasks](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Tasks) compared to the Java plugin. So you need to pick a different build task to depend your `copyTestResources` task on, for example:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

// (...) more build logic

task copyTestResources() {
    from "${projectDir}/src/test/resources"
    into "${buildDir}/classes/test"
}
check.dependsOn copyTestResources
```

Also, your `copyTestResources` task can be a little simpler like so:

```
task copyTestResources() {
    from sourceSets.test.resources
    into sourceSets.test.output.classesDir
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I still couldn't get my tests to work, see the edit of my answer. Perhaps you can have another look? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice workaround to put this to work.:
https://github.com/nenick/AndroidStudioAndRobolectric/blob/master/app/build.workaround-missing-resource.gradle

With this you can drop your extra task just add the ".gradle" file i linked and apply it in your modules ***build.gradle***.

```
apply from: 'build.workaround-missing-resource.gradle'
```

Make sure to put your assets into ***app/test/resources/*** and reference them via their name only.

e.g.: `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("my-asset-file.json")`

I found the solution in the ticket you linked.:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64887